# Multer is not uploading image from React

Tags: reactjs, forms, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

## Upload is not working here (passed as middleware)     only createpost working i tested it

```
//Frontend
const handlePost = async () => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("userId", _id);
      formData.append("description", post);
      if (image) {
        // console.log(image);
        formData.append("picture", image);
        formData.append("picturePath", image.name);
      }
      // console.log(formData);
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/posts`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`  },
        body: formData,
      });
      const posts = await response.json();
      dispatch(setPosts({ posts }));
      setImage(null);
      setPost("");
    };

//Backend

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/auth/register", upload.single("picture"), register);
app.post("/posts", upload.single("picture"), createPost);
```

i am trying to send image through react in frontend by appending in form  but upload.single("picture") is not picking it up